# Update others cells in a DataGrid row after editing one

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, updatesourcetrigger

I have a class like this:

```
public class Example
{
     public Example()
     {
     }

     public int Count1 { get; set; }

     public int Count2 { get; set; }

     public int Count3 { get { return Count1 + Count2 ; } }
}
```

And a DataGrid with a `List<Example>` as ItemSource:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdExample" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count1 , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Header="Count1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count1 , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Header="Count1" />

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count2 , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Header="Count2" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count3}"  Header="Count3" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want that when I edit the Count1 or Count2 column , the Count3 updates too .

With this code, just the second column (that is the same property then first coumn) has been changed.

I tried to refresh Items of the grid in SelectedCellsChanged event. But causes StackOverFlow, once the event keep changing on each refresh.

What Am i missing ? I look up for the solution, but without success.

PS: Debbuging I can see that the values are correct in grdExample.Items

Comment: I don't how you binding data to datagrid but have you tried with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your model class `Example`. Whenever the value is changed in UI, model will get notification and In your model class you can update `Count3` value as and when `Count1` & `Count2` changes.

This link can help you with `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface